# How to enable scrolling with a touchpad (IntelliJ)?

Tags: intellij-idea, scroll, key-bindings, touchpad

I just downloaded the latest release of IntelliJ and recognized that I can't scroll in the code while using the touchpad of my notebook. I tried to add a mouse binding to the scroll actions but it doesn't work.
My touchpad works fine with all other programms btw.

Comment: Does it work in other Java Swing apps like NetBeans or JEdit? What OS and hardware do you use?

Comment: It works fine with eclipse too. Im using a Lenovo Ideapad 510s with Win10.

Comment: update: it doesn't work in all other JetBrains IDE's

Comment: This bug is present 16 years

Comment: 18 years and counting it seems.

Comment: I went to the site support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds502969 and downloaded the ELAN driver and now it scrolls